# Проблема с вёрсткой

Tags: вёрстка, html, css

Всем привет, делал систему комментариев, и "воткнулся" с вот этой проблемой
[image]

Когда один комментарий хорошо, но когда добавляю второй и третий они съезжают...( помогите уже час сижу мучаюсь
Вот html код:

```
<div class = "comments span8">

    <div class = "comment">

      <div class = "comment_foto">
        <a href = ""><img src = "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-GtNAeoTiDhc/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/yhGEmfrFDrA/s48-c-k/photo.jpg"></a>
      </div>
      <div  class = "span7">
        <div class = "comment_info">
          <a href = "">Алексей Скляр</a> 
          <span><a href = "">3 д 19 ч назад</a></span>
        </div>
        <div class = "comment_text">
          <p> Далее я привожу несколько ресурсов, которые в режиме online формируют нужный нам html на основе оригинального кода. Далее я привожу несколько ресурсов, которые в режиме online формируют нужный нам html на основе оригинального кода. Далее я привожу несколько ресурсов, которые в режиме online формируют нужный нам html на основе оригинального кода. Далее я привожу несколько ресурсов, которые в режиме online формируют нужный нам html на основе оригинального кода.</p>
        </div>
        <div class = "comment_bottom">
          <span><a href = "">Ответить</a></span>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
```

Вот CSS:

> ```
>     .comment {
>   margin-bottom: 20px;
> }
> .comment_foto{
>   float: left;
>   margin-right: -15px;
> } 
> .comment_info a{
>   font-size: 15px;
>   color:#488EC6;
>   font-weight: bold;
> }
> .comment_info span a{
>   color:#9E9E9E;
>   margin-left: 10px;
>   font-size: 13px;
> }
> .comment_info span a:hover {
>   color:#4D91C8;
> }
> .comment_text {
>   font-size: 13px;
> }
> .comment_bottom span a{ 
>   color:#9E9E9E;
> }
> .comment_bottom span a:hover{ 
>   color:#4D91C8;
>   font-weight: bold;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте класс .clearfix для .comment, скорее всего проблема из-за того, что Вы не обнуляете float:left;

Вот сам класс:

```
.clearfix:after {
   content: " "; 
   visibility: hidden;
   display: block;
   height: 0;
   clear: both;
}
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: .clearfix у меня в бутстрапе есть и так, но что-то не подумал использовать его, спасибо!!!